# TypeError: validate() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7

I tried several times, but I can not resolve the error.
My python code looks like this:

```
def validate(item,key):
    if key in item:
        if isinstance( item[key], ( int, long, float) ):
            stro=str(item[key])
            if stro.lower()=="true":
                return "1"
            if stro.lower()=="false":
                return "0"
            return str(item[key])

        stro= item[key].encode('ascii', 'replace')
        return stro.replace("'","''")
    else:
        return "null"

for sport in oddsjson:
    pv_id = validate(sport.get("id"))
    pv_name= validate(sport,get("name"))
    sql= "INSERT INTO odds_sports(pv_id,pv_name) VALUES ('"
    sql= sql+ pv_id + "','"
    sql= sql+ pv_name + "')"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
```

It sends this error

```
pv_id = validate(sport.get("id"))
TypeError: validate() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is as straightforward as it gets.

`def validate(item, key)`

`validate` expects 2 arguments: `item` and `key`.

However, you only provide one:

```
pv_id = validate(sport.get("id"))
```

Bonus points:

1. You have a typo on the next line:

   ```
   pv_name = validate(sport,get("name"))
                        #  ^ comma
   ```

   should be

   ```
   pv_name = validate(sport.get("name"))
                        #  ^ dot
   ```
2. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use a parameterized query instead of concatenating queries.

   ```
   sql = "INSERT INTO odds_sports(pv_id, pv_name) VALUES (?, ?)"  # or %s, depending on
                                                                  # the library/connector
                                                                  # you are using
   cursor.execute(sql, (pv_id, pv_name))
   ```